# JWT Signing and encoding: overkill or a good idea

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

context: I'm authenticating a node.js app through jwt's using localStorage.

After reading a lot of opinions on this I'm quite confused.
I have an implementation which logs in the user with this code:

```
var payload = jwts.encode({id: user.id}, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
```

This is a little simplified. However, I'm wondering if the encoding is really necessary. Should I go for this instead?

```
var payload = {id: user.id};
var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
```

I don't have overly sensitive data in the payload but I will be adding claims which could be seen and exploited(user's computer is compromised and the localStorage would show they are a 'admin' user). It's not an ecommerce site but I would like it to be secure in the above (probably unlikely) scenario.

The negative is it makes the token larger (about 30% larger) so this will effect performance. Do the extra few characters really matter given the bandwidth people have nowadays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed option is not allowed by [RFC 7519 Json Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-6). jWT uses JWS compact serialization and each part must base64 url encoded

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by
> period ('.') characters.  **Each part contains a base64url-encoded
> value.**  The number of parts in the JWT is dependent upon the
> representation of the resulting JWS using the JWS Compact
> Serialization or JWE using the JWE Compact Serialization

Sending a JWT without serialization means you need to deal with encodings. Take a look to JWS RFC if you want to see differences between compact and flattened serialization https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#page-19

Comment: thanks for the snippet. A couple of points: the token is still base64 encoded, it's base64 encoding the encoded 'payload' variable. Also, even though the specification states that jwt's are base64 encoded, libraries allow many different types through algorithms: value in the options section

Comment: Yes, when building the JWT, the JSON payload is  **base64 url encoded** It is a standard algorithm, applies base64 encoding and after replaces a couple of characters